# Pushing an Object to en emptry Array in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to push an object into an empty array in vue, but when i'm doing it like below, the console.log will give me "hitlist: [Object object]

the code:

```js
data: () => {
    return {
        list: [],
        hitlist: [],
        searchText: ""
    };
},
methods: {
    searchJoke: function(e) {
        this.searchText = e;

        for (let i = 0; i < this.list.length; i++) {
            if (this.list[i].title.includes(this.searchText)) {
                this.hitlist.push(this.list[i]);
                console.log("Hitlist: " + this.hitlist[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in the "e" is the string i want to compare with my title in the list array, if the title contains the word then it should push the whole Object in the list array with this title into the Array hitList, but it seems i don't know any further to solve this problem.

The list Array is filled with objects that contain the following:

```
[{
"id":0,"title":"Zwei Bomben im Keller","text":"Sind zwei Bomben im Keller, sagt die eine zur anderen:\"Lass mal hochgehen.\"","rating":4},
{"id":1,"title":"Mönche in Asien","text":"Hoch in den japanischen Bergen fragt der Zen-Schüler seinen Meister: „Meister Aikodo, warum denken die Europäer, dass wir alle gleich aussehen? - Antwortet der Meister: „Ich bin nicht Meister Aikodo.","rating":5},
{"id":2,"title":"Privatsphäre","text":"Natürlich müsste ich mal die Fenster putzen, aber Privatsphäre ist auch wichtig.","rating":2},
{"id":3,"title":"Fieser Peter","text":"Susanne: Hallöchen! Peter: Hallöchen! - Susanne: Wie geht es dir! Peter: Wie geht es dir! - Susanne: Äffst du mich nach?! Peter: Äffst du mich nach?! - Susanne: Ich bin hässlich (grinst) Peter: Ja, das stimmt.","rating":5},
{"id":4,"title":"Teewitz","text":"Welchen Tee sollte man besser nicht trinken? - TNT","rating":4},
{"id":5,"title":"Verrückter Papa","text":"Sohn: Papi, ab wann zählt jemand als verrückt? - Vater: Das ist, wenn jemand etwas sagt aber man ihn nicht versteht. Verstehst du das? - Sohn: Nein","rating":3},
{"id":6,"title":"Im Zug","text":"Im Zug: Könnten Sie Ihrem Sohn bitte sagen, er soll aufhören, mich zu imitieren. - Fritzchen, hör bitte auf so dämlich zu tun.","rating":2},
{"id":7,"title":"Frauen und Hosen","text":" Frau: Machen mich diese Hosen dick. - Man: Kein Ahnung. Ich würde sie jedenfalls nicht essen.","rating":1},
{"id":8,"title":"Dachbox","text":"Ich habe mir endlich so eine Dachbox für das Auto geholt. Echt praktisch muss ich sagen. Die Kinder hört man kaum noch.","rating":3},{"id":9,"title":"Japanische","text":"Haben Japaner eigentlich Angst vor Godzilla? - Ja panische.","rating":4},
{"id":10,"title":"Der Mathelehrer","text":"Was steht auf dem Grabstein eines Mathelehrers? – Damit hat er nicht gerechnet!","rating":3.5
}]
```

Again, my goal here is to compare the searchtext String with the title of every list entry, if the comparison returns true this entry should then be stored in the hitlist Array.

If you guy have any clue, please let me know, i appricate your help and your work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [**computed properties**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) for your problem, just add an computed property called `hitList` which filters the list by `searchText` by `list.filter(...)`:

```
data() {
  return {
    list: [],
    searchText: '',
  };
},
computed: {
  hitList() {
    return this.list.filter(({ title }) => {
       return title.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchText.toLowerCase());
    });
  },
},
```

And in your template just use the `hitlist` to render the list:

```
<input type="text v-model="searchText">
<ul>
  <li v-for="joke in hitList">
    ...
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Okay this kind of solves the problem, but im Passing the hitlist  to a component, and when i try to acess the title/text/id or the rating in this component via the passed hitlist, it won't show anything.
So the computed function seems to work but still i can acess the properties via interpolation in the passed hitList Array :/
example:
{{hitList.title}} or {{hitList.text}} dosen't display anything

Comment: Nevermind i found the issue, i need to adress joke.title, not hitList.title
Stupid me :D